# How to customize the Android built-in calendar?

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

Can i customize the android calendar the day view?

Thanks.

Edit:
I try these project:

[android-calendar-view](http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/), but it cannot work in XVGA.

[android-calendarview](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-calendarview), it work as the android built in Calendar. But, it cannot customize the day view.

Comment: Also tell us what you have tried so far..

Comment: *cannot custom the day view* => Then Can't you try to implement by your own?

Comment: i just want to find a good solution. You know my bad coding